# Pygame returning black screen even though other parts of the same script are working

Tags: python

Im following a tutorial on Youtube which results in displaying a red blob/dot on a white background. I am only getting a black screen instead of the expected result.

I've tried to find any errors in the code but cant find any. When i run the code i am presented with a window with a black background and nothing on it. The only part of the code that is working is the exit button. I would think that if that part of the script is working, all of it would be working but i guess i still messed up. Help would be much appreciated.

This is my code:

```
import pygame
import random

width = 800
height = 600
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("2D Blob world")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class blob:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.x = random.randrange(0,width)
        self.y = random.randrange(0,height)
        self.size = random.randrange(5,10)
        self.color = color

    def move(self):
        self.x += random.randrange(-5,5)
        self.y += random.randrange(-5,5)

        if self.x >width:
                self.x = width
        elif self.x <0:
                self.x = 0

        if self.y >height:
                self.y = height
        elif self.y <0:
                self.y = 0

def draw_environment(blob):
        game_display.fill((white))
        pygame.draw.circle(game_display, blob.color,(blob.x, blob.y), blob.size)
        pygame.display.update()

def main():
    red_blob = blob(red)    
    while True:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()
    draw_environment(red_blob)
    clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()

draw_environment(red_blob)
```

What it should get as a result is a red dot on a white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the above code is inside the main method's definition. You are creating a blob object and then going inside an infinite loop, instead of drawing the environment first.
To fix it you need to move draw_environment(red_blob)  from line 48 to after line 41, so that your main method looks like this:

```
def main():
    red_blob = blob(red)
    draw_environment(red_blob) 
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
    clock.tick(60)
```

You may also want to move the clock.tick(60) method to somewhere above also as you need it to be.

Comment: This solution completely works for me. I never considered it. Thank you very much.